# JavaScript OOP to FP

Tags: javascript, oop

I`m having problem with converting my code from OOP to Function. Please show me a way.
Thanks a lot.

```
const basket = document.querySelector('.basket_icon');

basket.addEventListener('click', chartVisblity);

function chartVisblity() {
    const chart = document.querySelector('.chart');
    const visbl = chart.style.display;
    if (visbl === "block") {
        chart.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        chart.style.display = "block";

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you consider OOP in that snippet and what would need to change to become FP?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the usage of the DOM Model, your code is in the form of a function, and it is not Object Oriented in the sense that it uses a method of an object class instead of an independently defined function.

It seems like you've already achieved your goal!